# Print values of the reference object in for loop

Tags: r

I have data which saves in a object with some sequence. I need to print all values using for loop.
here is the example

```
a1 <- 1
a2 <- 2
a3 <- 3

for(i in 1:3)
  print(paste0('a',i))
```

it is actually printing a1,a2,a3. but I need to get the values of those variables

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a `for` loop, would something like `cat(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "a\\d"))), sep = "\n")` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
> for(i in 1:3)   print(get(paste0('a',i)))
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

Comment: `get(paste0("xlag",1))[!(get(paste0("xlag",1))==x)] <- NA` here the code, I am trying to assign NA to those matching values, but it is giving error

Comment: use != for not equal to.

Comment: `a1 <- 1:10;a2 <- 1:10;a3 <- 1:10;a4 <- 1:10

for(i in 1:4)
  get(paste0('a',i))[get(paste0('a',i)) != 5] <-NA` is showing error as **Error in get(paste0("a", i))[get(paste0("a", i)) != 5] <- NA : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object** please help

Comment: The question is not clear. It is better to post it as a separate detailed question.